# Active record in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, php

Anybody can convert this query to active record codeigniter???

```
 SELECT  b.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) S,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) M,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) L,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'XL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) XL
   FROM    orderTB a
    INNER JOIN productTB b
        ON a.id_product = b.id_shirt
    INNER JOIN sizeTB c
        ON a.id_size = c.id_size
GROUP BY b.name
```

i've tried like this

```
  function get()
 {
  $this->db->select("b.name,SUM(CASE WHEN c.size ='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as S,SUM(CASE    WHEN c.size = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as M,SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as   L,SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'XL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as XL");

 $this->db->from('order');
 $this->db->join('ukuran','order.id_size=ukuran.id_size');
 $this->db->where('date',$date);
 return $this->db->get();
 }
```

but its wrong

Comment: Shouldn't you rather have `SELECT b.name, c.size, COUNT(*) FROM ... GROUP BY b.name, c.size`, and reorganize the data later?

Comment: Add FALSE as your 2nd parameter to your select

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just try this one and let me know,

```
$this->db->select("b.name,SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) S,SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) M,SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) L,SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'XL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) XL", FALSE );
$this->db->from('orderTB a');
$this->db->join('productTB b','a.id_product = b.id_shirt','inner');
$this->db->join('sizeTB c','a.id_size = c.id_size','inner');
$this->db->group_by('b.name');
```

From document [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set
>   it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select
>   statement.

**EDIT**

Just add `FALSE` in your select statement

```
function get() {
    $this->db->select("b.name,SUM(CASE WHEN c.size ='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as S,SUM(CASE    WHEN c.size = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as M,SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as   L,SUM(CASE WHEN c.size = 'XL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as XL",FALSE);

    $this->db->from('order');
    $this->db->join('ukuran','order.id_size=ukuran.id_size');
    $this->db->where('date',$date);
    return $this->db->get();
}
```