# Determine a column that gets a match when I check 2 columns with "or"

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE City = 'Berlin'
   OR Country = 'Germany';
```

When I get a result, I need to know if the result is because there was a match in the `City` column or in the Country column.

Comment: Why do you use this condition at all? Berlin is in germany so `WHERE country='germany'` is sufficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter country could be null

Comment: @booyaa: so you mean that `Berlin` records dont have a `Country`? Wouldn't make sense but ok.

Comment: It was just an example. I agree i could have found a better one.
like this:
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE car_colour = 'white'
   OR house_colour = 'white';

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, 
       case when City='Berlin' 
            then 'city'
            else 'country'
       end as match_result
FROM Customers 
WHERE City='Berlin' 
OR country='germany'
```

Comment: When you look at the `match_result` column.

Comment: I am using codeigniter. can this be used with the active recordes?
this is my code:

  $this->db->select('*');

  $this->db->from('lawyers');
  
  $this->db->like('full_name', $search);

  $this->db->or_like('specialties_1', $search); 

  $this->db->or_like('specialties_2', $search); 

   $this->db->or_like('detailes', $search);
 
   $data['lawyers'] = $this->db->get( );

Comment: Found something of this sort but still can not translate my query to active records codeigniter:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110064/active-record-in-codeigniter

Comment: Sorry, I never worked with Codeignator. If you can't get it to work, ask another question and be as specific as possible and don't forget to tag the question with codeignator too